# Select date index with pandas DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have following pandas dataframe `selected_symbol_log`:

```
         symbol   price  shares action
date                                    
2010-01-20    UNP  31.865     313    buy
2010-01-21    UNP  32.725    -313  cover
```

What I want is to select rows using variable last_cover containing pandas `DatatimeIndex:

```
last_cover:  DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-21'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'date', freq=None)
```

I do:

```
selected_symbol_log[selected_symbol_log.index>last_cover]
```

This use to work before, but perhaps after pandas update I get error:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

What I found out is that

```
selected_symbol_log[selected_symbol_log.index> '2010-01-21'
```

is working. But why my original condition stopped working and what is the way to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare with one value. Use `last_cover[0]`:

```
selected_symbol_log[selected_symbol_log.index>last_cover[0]]
```

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you have the privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). ;)